# Hide/show UIToolbar/Navbar using link

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm using Photoswipe in my app and it is working very nice. Right now I have a toolbar and a navbar, so when viewing the photos in "fullscreen" the toolbar and navbar is still visible, so the it is not actually a fullscreen. I'm wondering however if it could be possible to hide/show the toolbar/navbar depending on when an image is clicked/dismissed.

I found this which will hide the toolbar

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

        self.navController.hidden = YES;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

So far so good, but how do I get the toolbar **back** when the user clicks the exit button in Photoswipe (which is essential just another link)?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tend to find that relying on UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked or indeed any kind of webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: is going to give you inconsistent results. I recommend using [JSBridge](http://code.google.com/p/jsbridge-to-cocoa/), with which you can create a dictionary object that will be passed to Cocoa. With this, you can guarantee capturing the event and load your event with custom information for it.

For this, you create a JSBridgeWebView (subclass of UIWebView) and setup the delegate to handle:

```
-(void) webView:(UIWebView*)webView didReceiveJSNotificationWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*) dictionary { 
    NSLog(@"Received notification dictionary %@", dictionary);
}
```

Then add in a quick JavaScript function:

```
function sendShowToolBarNotification() { 
    var obj = new JSBridgeObj();
    obj.addObject("eventName", "showToolBar");
    obj.sendBridgeObject();
}
```

Now you can have a link that will send this notification to your application:

```
<a href="javascript:sendShowToolBarNotification()">Click here to show toolbar</a>
```